# Countif number matches pattern in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

How can I count the number of cells in a column that start with a specified prefix of 3 characters, and have a total length of 6 characters?

E.g. for the column

```
123000
123001
123002
546000
1230101
```

and the prefix `123`, I want to return the number 3, for the cells that have `123000`, `123001`, `123002` (but not `1230101` because it is too long).

I tried `=COUNTIF(A:A, "123???")`, but that just returns 0.

[image]

I guess that it returns 0 because the contents of the cells are considered to be numbers by excel, but the lookup pattern is a string, so it never matches. I then tried `=COUNTIF(TEXT(A:A, "0"), "123???")` to fix this, but that just causes an error that I don't even know how to find the error reason for.

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun one! Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">122999", A:A, "<123999")
```

I think your original formula was not working because the values in column A are numbers, not text, so the wildcard search would not work.

Edit: forget the A:1 comment - I was thinking you were going to use a helper column and total them.

Comment: `"<123999"` should be `"<124000"`, otherwise you would miss the 123999 case...

Answer (score 1):

Because these are number you should use criteria for numbers, not for text. So in this specific case you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=123000", A:A, "<=123999")
```

or more generally, if your prefix `123` is in a cell, let's say `B1` you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=" & $B$1*1000, A:A, "<=" & $B$1*1000+999)
```

Another possible approach is to treat numbers as text and use `SUM` function:

```
=SUM((LEN(A1:A100)=6)*(LEFT(A1:A100,3)="123"))
```

But in this case I recommend to avoid full column reference.

Comment: Why avoid full column reference in the last case?

Comment: Because it slows down the formula. You can also use Excel Tables to restrict data ranges to really used.

Answer (score 1):

*There are multiple ways of doing this. I will try to outline few of those ways.*

---

Your **first formula** is not working because the data type of **criteria_range** is numeric while the **criteria** is text.

It should have worked if the data type of the **criteria_range** is formatted as text. Refer screenshot :

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIF(A9:A13,B9&"???")
```

---

But there is drawback to the above formula, as you can see in the range `A9:A13` are greedy to be formatted as numbers, when clicking on those red checkmarks, the first option says `Number Stored As Text` and the second one is `Convert To Number`, if anyone mistakenly converts them to numbers then your formula will return `0` and hence it should be avoided.

---

The **second formula** of yours is not working because `COUNTIF()` function deals with an `Excel Range` therefore any formula used inside `COUNTIFS()` **criteria range** returns an `array`. Essentially some functions, including all of the `IFs` family of functions like `SUMIF()`,`COUNTIFS()`, `AVERAGEIFS()` etc. all require `ranges` in the `criteria range` param.

This also explains why such functions can't be used to extract data from closed workbooks, because data is extracted from closed workbooks as an `array`.

---

However, you could try the following, which may make it relatively easy to use and adapt.

[image]

---

• <sup>*</sup>Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM(--IFNA(LEN(TEXTAFTER(A1:A5,B1))=3,))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(--LEFT(RIGHT(A1:A5,6),3)=B1))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(--REPLACE(A1:A5,4,3,)=B1))
```

---

**Note:** <sup>*</sup> this requires `MS365` due to `TEXTAFTER()` function. Also based on ones `Excel` Version, one may or may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode. `MS365` users don't require the above keying.

Lastly, as already mentioned, you shouldn't use the whole range, because it slows down the working functionality of `Excel` instead convert your source range/list into `Structured References` aka `Tables` which makes it easier to use within formulas as well as it resizes automatically when there is a change in the data sizes, like if you delete some rows or add rows, the formula will adapt to it automatically.

---